# Why do Java MD5 and PHP MD5 deliver entirely different results?

Tags: java, php, md5, sha1

While preparing access data for a website, I suddenly got aware of the fact that the MD5 encrypted passwords created by Java are not at all the same as those created by PHP MD5. Looking through the postings here and elsewhere I found several solutions in Java assuring that the would deliver exactly the same result as PHP - but all Java implementations deliver the same result among themselves but an entirely different result from the one by PHP.

I therefore wrote a small Java program sending the same password to my local server for conversion by PHP, and at the same time converting it by itself using Java. Here the program:

```
public PHPDriver() {
  String pwd = "aabbccdd";
  String p = encodeByPHP("http://localhost/testsite/md5.php?pwd=" + pwd);
  System.out.println("PHPDriver:       " + pwd + " -> " + p);

  System.out.println("md5:             " + pwd + " -> " + md5(p));
...
public String encodeByPHP(String url) {
  try {
    // create a link to  a URL
    URL urlAddress = new URL(url);
    URLConnection link = urlAddress.openConnection();
    BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.getInputStream()));
    return inStream.readLine();  
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
...
public String md5(String input)  {
  String result = input;
  try {
    if(input != null) {
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); //or "SHA-1"
      md.update(input.getBytes());
      BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
      result = hash.toString(16);
      while(result.length() < 32) {
        result = "0" + result;
      }
    }
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa) {
```

And the (overwhelmingly complicated;-) PHP page:

```
<?php
  $pwd = $_GET['pwd'];
  // echo $pwd . ' -> ';
  echo sha1($pwd); 
?>
```

The result of this looks as follows:

```
PHPDriver:       aabbccdd -> 527bee2730bf234e9a78bde5af091ece9c6302d5
md5:             aabbccdd -> ab86815613f7f321001efef1935dbe7d
```

What's going wrong here? Is this an mis-encoding problem? And why is the PHP result 40 char's long instead of the usual 32?

Comment: It looks like your php code uses the SHA1 hashing algorithm, while your java code uses MD5...

Comment: Note the *length* of the outputs; SHA-1 is 160bits, 20 bytes, 40 hex characters; MD5 128 bits, 16 byes, 32 hex characters.

Comment: Apropos of nothing, and perhaps you can't change your existing codebase, but neither sha1 nor md5 are appropriate for hashing passwords.  http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: I'm really sorry that I missed to change back sha1 to md5. But the main problem remains: The results have equal length but are totally different.

Answer (score 4):

Your returning sha1 from your PHP script

Instead Use:

```
<?php
  $pwd = $_GET['pwd'];
  // echo $pwd . ' -> ';
  echo md5($pwd); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `sha1` in one and `md5` in the other, you're not specifying a `Charset` when you call `String.getBytes()` in Java.  This can result in unpredictable behavior.  Specifying a `Charset` like UTF-8 will get consistent results, and then you can check in PHP how to make sure you're hashing the string with UTF-8.

Comment: You should indeed always specify the character encoding. But I wouldn't call it *unpredictable* if you don't; if you don't specify the character encoding, the default character encoding of the system will be used. And if that's different from what PHP uses, the results will obviously be different.

Comment: If you're plugging the results into a hash function, and expecting to get the same output every time, I'd call it a bona fide bug not to specify the encoding.